# JAX-RS, When POST fails, how to get raw JSON

Tags: java, json, exception, post, resteasy

my code uses an external API. When I call it with a correct parameter, I get the expected answer.

When I call it with a wrong parameter (wrong in the sense of incorrect job's data, technical is OK), my code throws an Exception. I was expecting a String containing the data's validation error "sex='3' is wrong".

The API uses JSON and return JSON. I call it with javax.ws.rs

Here is my method where I call the API

```
    public final String API_URL= "http://sv-t-vtl-pgih-vidal:9900/solfeges/api/v0";

    private void test(String json)
    {
        // The proxy for calling the API.
        SolfegesServices proxy = ProxyFactory.create(SolfegesServices.class, API_URL);

        // 
        try
        {
            // Call the API
            String retourBrut = proxy.callfactureapi(json);

            System.out.println(retourBrut);
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here an other class I use to declare the API

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

import fr.pgih.ope.act.dim.gestionfides.utils.RetourSolfegesException;

@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public interface SolfegesServices
{
    @POST
    @Path("/factures")
    public String callfactureapi(String json) throws RetourSolfegesException;
}
```

Those both classes are enought to call the API.

When the API is called with incorrect data, the API returns a JSON with a 422 status. When it happens, the code throws a runtimeException that does not contains API's info about the error.

**How can I get the JSON returned by the API in case of error?**

NB.
In case of success, the JSON looks like

```
{
statut:200,
message:"succes",
b2:"some content"
}
```

In case of failure, I'm expecting something like

```
{
statut:422, (or 400)
message:"fail to...",
reason:"sexe='3' is incorrect"
}
```

I've already dig the whole stackoverflow website and some other without finding a solution to my problems, despite of the amount of similar cases.

Everything looks fine if I try to call the API with Postman (external tool to execute web requests).

Answer (score 0):

You can return the ResponseEntity from your controller. The response entity can be based on the validation failure you mention and this json message should be part of the body.

`ResponseEntity response = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY).body(jsonMessage).build();`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I integrated API's tool to call it (using Swagger). And it ... works ... almost perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Finally (the comeback). I've surcharged the exception filter to catch them (http statut 400 or 422).

ClientResponseFilter.filter(ClientRequestContext reqCtx, ClientResponseContext resCtx)

```
public class ClientResponsesExceptionFilter implements ClientResponseFilter
{

    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext reqCtx, ClientResponseContext resCtx)
            throws ApiSolfegesException, IOException
    {
        if (resCtx.getStatus() == Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST.getStatusCode() || resCtx.getStatus() == 422)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I use it here

```
@Override
    public ModelApiResponse facturesPost(DossiersPmsi body)
    {

        CustomResteasyJackson2Provider resteasyJacksonProvider = new CustomResteasyJackson2Provider();

        // Ajout d'un Mapper pour gérer la sérialisation et désrialisation json des dates proprement
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
        javaTimeModule.addDeserializer(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateDeserializer());
        javaTimeModule.addSerializer(new LocalDateSerializer());
        mapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule);
        resteasyJacksonProvider.setMapper(mapper);

        // ajout d'un filtre pour les exception
        ClientResponsesExceptionFilter filter = new ClientResponsesExceptionFilter();

        // appel de l'api solfeges
        ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().register(resteasyJacksonProvider)
                .register(filter).build();
        ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(UriBuilder.fromPath(URL_SOLFEGE));
        FacturesApi proxy = target.proxy(FacturesApi.class);
        return proxy.facturesPost(body);
    }
```

I also use these to get the JSON
from : https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/javax.ws.rs.client.ClientResponseContext/getEntityStream

```
private String getResponseBody(ClientResponseContext context) throws IOException
    {
        // La variable qui contient la description de l'erreur dans un fichier JSON.
        String jsonEchec = null;

        // Essayer de récupérer le JSON
        try (InputStream entityStream = context.getEntityStream())
        {
            if (entityStream != null)
            {
                byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(entityStream);
                context.setEntityStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
                jsonEchec = new String(bytes);
            }
        }

        // Retour du JSON descriptif de l'erreur
        return jsonEchec;
    }
```